# Limit jQuery UI checkbox selection to one and updating textbox when checkbox value is selected

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to limit the jQuery UI checkbox selection to one?

Secondly, once checkbox selection has been limited to one, is there a way to update the content of the checkbox with whatever value the user has selected?

Currently my checkbox is allowing for multi-selection, here is my code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/wDbUF/1/

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" style="border: 0; color: #000; background-color: #fff; font-size: 12px;" disabled="disabled" value="None" class="check"/>
<div id="format">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check1"/><label for="check1">1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check2" /><label for="check2">2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check3" /><label for="check3">3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check4" /><label for="check4">4</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check5" /><label for="check5">5</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check6" /><label for="check6">6</label>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#check" ).button();
    $( "#format" ).buttonset();
});​
```

Comment: I guess the obvious solution is to use radio buttons. http://jsfiddle.net/3leven11/wDbUF/7/

Answer (score 1):

Change the input type from `checkbox` to `radio`. That should fix your problem. Also give a `name` attribute which should be same for all `radio` inputs,

```
<input type="text" style="border: 0; color: #000; background-color: #fff; font-size: 12px;" disabled="disabled" value="None" class="check"/>

<div id="format">
    <input type="radio" name="check" id="check1"/><label for="check1">1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="check" id="check2" /><label for="check2">2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="check" id="check3" /><label for="check3">3</label>
    <input type="radio" name="check" id="check4" /><label for="check4">4</label>
    <input type="radio" name="check" id="check5" /><label for="check5">5</label>
    <input type="radio" name="check" id="check6" /><label for="check6">6</label>
</div>
 ​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wDbUF/4/